# Wordpress user signup

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication

I want to allow users to signup without admin authentication. I don't want to set individual roles.
I have tried few plugins but they don't seem to provide the required features.

Comment: What features do you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Below function will redirect users back to homepage and will not allow access to Users:-

```
function themeblvd_redirect_admin(){
wp_redirect( site_url() );
    exit;       
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'themeblvd_redirect_admin' );
```

You may also need to disable admin bar on the frontend of your website:-

```
function themeblvd_disable_admin_bar() { 
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false'); 
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'themeblvd_disable_admin_bar' );
```

You have to add these functions in functions.php of your theme.

Comment: Thank you for the code. It seems to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Dashboard (wp-admin) -> Settings -> General -> Tick "Anyone can register" and make sure "Subscriber" is set below.